# How to properly install ssl to apache2 OVH vps

Tags: apache, ssl

I uploaded my certificates to my apache2 server but cant properly map everything. I have attached screenshots of the sites-available folder and the default-ssl file. How can I map this properly. Everytime I update the virtualhost in defualt-ssl my server wont restart.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I see you did the Wordpress install. If that is the only site you have on there this will be easy! I just bought an OVH VPS SSD 1 and ran into this issue myself.

First, you will have to add your SSLCertificateChainFile to your default-ssl.conf file.

My certs and keys are as follows:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/SSL/2_www.xxxnoscopemlgxxx.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/SSL/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/SSL/1_root_bundle.crt
```

Second, you are on the right path. In default-ssl.conf at the very top you will see:

```
DocumentRoot: /var/www/html
```

Change that to:

```
DocumentRoot: /var/www/wordpress
```

Almost done!

Next, on your site, in the Wordpress admin panel, go to Settings > General

There you will see

```
WordPress Address (URL)
```

And

```
Site Address (URL)
```

Next to both of those enter your domain name with an https:// in front of them. (depending on your cert I'd recommend https://www.yourdomain.tld)

Now, in your OVH manager, restart the server and you should be able to use your Wordpress site with full SSL support.

You can configure Apache to redirect all http traffic to https if you want.

I know this post is 6 months old and you have probably figured out what was wrong by now. However, I came across this post when I was trying to figure out what I was doing wrong yesterday and when I noticed the DocumentRoot not pointing to the Wordpress directory I felt like an idiot.

I just wanted to give this answer for anyone having this issue in the future.